# Numeric Textbox - Formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a disabled textbox that shows a calculated percentage. 
I am looking to format this text box to always show a single decimal place, even if the number is a whole number.

I feel like this should be simple, but for some reason I can't figure this out.

Any suggestions?

```
<div class="labelReallySmall">
                @Html.Label("%F", null, new { @class = "req" })
                @Html.TextBox("PFat305", null, new { disabled = true })
                     <script>
                         $(document).ready(function () {
                             $("#305Fat").change(function () {
                                 var a = parseInt($(this).val());
                                 var b = parseInt($("#Milk305").val());
                                 var c = (a*100)/b ;
                                 $("#PFat305").val(c);
                             });
                         });
                </script>
            </div>
```

Thanks in advance, Mark

Comment: what code have you tried so far? show some markup. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you looked at JavaScript's math functions like parseInt(), parseFloat() and toFixed()?

Comment: I have calculated my percentage, but this is where I stuck, I don't know how I should approach the next step. See edit.

Comment: Remember to check that you don't accidentally divide by zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.toFixed(n)` - where n - is number of decimals.

```
    alert((10.82).toFixed(1));
```

Comment: This works, it get's me the 1 decimal I was looking for, but it's always "0" for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

check the following code. Hopefully it will help you.

```
var percent = "35.5%"

var parsePercent = parseFloat(percent);
if (parsePercent == null)
alert("error");
else {
var decimal = parsePercent / 100
alert(decimal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use toFixed-function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#305Fat").change(function () {
        var a = parseFloat($(this).val()),
            b = parseFloat($("#Milk305").val()), c;
        if (b) { //to avoid dividing by null
            c = parseFloat((a*100)/b).toFixed(1);
            $("#PFat305").val(c);
        } else {
            //handle dividing by 0 here
        }                  
    });
});
```

---

Heres [a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tohveli/9prEX/1/) for testing. Decimal changes correctly, so if your decimal is wrong, maybe the error is somewhere else

Comment: This works, but it always returns a "0" as the decimal.

Comment: Problem might be somewhere else in your code @Mark, since the fiddle I just added works fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

toFixed is the right answer. But here is another (long) way to do it.

```
var nu = 78.988;
nu = Math.floor(nu * 10)/10;
```

alert(nu); // 78.9

Using 100 would be two decimal places, 1000 is 3, etc.